# While trying to read a file opened for output only, the eofbit flag is set for the stream. Why is that?

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("out.txt", ios_base::app);

    file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

    char buffer[100];

    if( !file.getline(buffer, 99) )
        cout << "file.failbit  " << boolalpha << file.fail() << "   file.eofbit   " << file.eof()
                 << '\n'
             << "file.badbit   " << file.bad() << "  file.goodbit  " << file.good() << '\n';

}
```

output

[image]

Comment: Is the file empty?  Trying to read from an empty file will set `eofbit`.

Comment: Well, when you can't read from the file, isn't it eof basically?

Comment: @MichaelKristofik It doesn't matter. The eofbit is always set.

Comment: I quickly searched through the standard and didn't find anything preventing you from reading a file opened for output.  That doesn't mean your standard library implementation wouldn't do it though.  What happens if you make the openmode `ios_base::in | ios_base::app`?

Comment: @MichaelKristofik It will read the file's first line, of course, as ios_base::app implies ios_base::out.

Comment: Found it.  The standard does prohibit you from reading from a file opened only for write.  Added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The standard prohibits you from reading from a file opened only for output.  From paragraph 27.9.1.1.3 on `basic_filebuf` (part of the underlying implementation of `fstream`):

> If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.

One would therefore expect to see `failbit` when trying to read from a file open only for writing.  The standard also says that `eofbit` is set whenever `getline` reaches the end of an input sequence.  Since you effectively have an empty input sequence (i.e., a file you can't read from), the first call to getline sets `eofbit` as well.  In standardese, the underlying stream buffer **underflows**.  `basic_streambuf::underflow()` returns `traits::eof()` on failure (see 27.6.3.4.3 paragraphs 7-17).

To fix this, add `ios_base::in` to the file's openmode.

Comment: I never had any doubts about the failbit. My question is about the eofbit. I'm still not convinced the eofbit should be set in this case though.

Comment: Added a reference the section that convinced me why you get eofbit too.